# Select all orders which have the same order items

Tags: mysql

I need to fetch all orders which have the same cart (same list of order items and quantity).

Here are my tables:

**orders** (I think columns are not important, the primary key is **id**)

```
| id |
| -- |
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
| ... |
```

**order_items**

| id | order_id | product_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 | 20.00 |
| 2 | 100 | 2 | 22.00 |
| 3 | 107 | 1 | 20.00 |
| 4 | 110 | 1 | 20.00 |
| 5 | 110 | 2 | 22.00 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

My goal is to use SQL to get orders 100 and 110 in this case. (They need to have the same rows containing the same product_id and quantity so order items number can vary, this is just an example). As you can see order 107 have the same order item but it's missing product id 2 with the quantity of 22.00 so it doesn't need to be included.

It's important to mention that this table will be large and probably it will contain 1M+ rows, maybe even more.

The ultimate goal is to have those groups of orders, for example, [100-110] but in reality, it would be like [100-110-...-n, x-y-z-...-n, ...]. The number of the same orders is not limited, that's why I used n in the example. My example only contains 2 orders that are the same.

The only thing I have achieved so far is to get the first group of orders with the query I've found on Stackoverflow:

```
SELECT DISTINCT O2.id
FROM orders O1
         INNER JOIN order_items I1 ON O1.id = I1.order_id
         INNER JOIN order_items I2 ON I1.product_id = I2.product_id AND I1.quantity = I2.quantity
         INNER JOIN orders O2 ON O2.id = I2.order_id
WHERE O1.id =
      (SELECT id FROM orders ORDER BY created_at LIMIT 1)
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_items WHERE order_id = O1.id)
    = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_items WHERE order_id = O2.id)
ORDER BY O2.id;
```

I tried to change it in order to return all orders but with no luck.

Comment: Do you need in **completely equal**  orders pairs? Aggregate the order data then compare these aggregated values. PS. If one order contains item=1 amount=10 and another one contains 2 rows for item=1 with anounts 4 and 6 - does these orders are equal?

Comment: @Akina The order cannot have 2 items with different amounts. It would be 10 instead of 2 separate rows for the same item.

Comment: *The order cannot have 2 items with different amounts* Does UNIQUE index by ```order_items (order_id, product_id)``` exists? if not then those duplicates **may** exist, nothing in the structure prevents this. Simply add complete CREATE TABLE for this table to the question.

Comment: There is no unique index on (order_id, product_id) but I can add it.

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojsa - you should have a `UNIQUE` index on `(order_id, product_id)` - it makes no sense to have the same item twice in the same order when you should be adding the totals!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is use a [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) to `COUNT()` how many products there are in every `order`, then join it to itself by `product_id`, `quantity`, and that `product_count`. That'll get you potential matches (which would include subset matches like two different `orders` with the same counts but each have one different product). Then with a window function again count how many rows actually matched between two `orders` and if the count of the matched rows is the same as the count of products in those `orders` then you know it's an exact match.

Something like this may work:

```
WITH order_items_counted AS
(
    SELECT
        id,
        order_id,
        product_id,
        quantity,
        COUNT(product_id) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id) AS product_count -- Counts how many products are in each order
    FROM order_items
),
potential_matches AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        O1.order_id,
        O1.product_count,
        COUNT(O1.id) OVER (PARTITION BY O1.order_id, O2.order_id) AS matched_row_count -- Counts how many order_line rows matched
    FROM order_items_counted AS O1
    INNER JOIN order_items_counted AS O2
        ON O1.order_id <> O2.order_id -- Different Orders
        AND O1.product_count = O2.product_count -- With the same # of Products
        AND O1.product_id = O2.product_id -- Which are the same Products
        AND O1.quantity = O2.quantity -- With the same Quantities
)

-- Finally get the exact matches by filtering out any partial matches (the matched row count <> the product count)
SELECT DISTINCT
    order_id
FROM potential_matches AS exact_matches
WHERE product_count = matched_row_count
```

I don't have a way to test it at the moment, so please let me know if you have any issues and I'll address them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! It works without any changes to your query

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojsa Great! No problem!

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH
cte AS (
    SELECT order_id, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(product_id, quantity ORDER BY product_id, quantity) order_content
    FROM order_items
    GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT t1.order_id, t2.order_id
FROM cte t1 
JOIN cte t2 USING (order_content)
WHERE t1.order_id < t2.order_id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/-mMek3QT

Comment: Can you please explain your approach and what your query does? @Akina

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojsa In CTE the whole order content is combined into one value with definite ordering. In outer query I simply compare this combined value for 2 different orders, and return only those pairs for which the values are completely the same. PS. I rename the column for the algo to be more clear.

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not return anything. It looks like you are only retrieving ids for 2 orders if I understand it? I need ids from all orders which have the same order items.

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojsa You do something wrongly. Answer updated, fiddle added. *I need ids from all orders which have the same order items.* Add desired output for shown data into your question.